# Safari kills Java applet which launched an (idle) JFileChooser

Tags: java, safari, applet, jfilechooser

I need to pop-up a file open dialog in a web page, and have the user select a file (not for upload!). Because I need access to the full file path, I cannot use a form/input. Thus, I use a signed Java applet.

In my test case a Java applet method is called from a javascript function. The applet method opens a file open dialog (JFileChooser). If left idle for approx. 30", the applet gets killed by Safari(*). In my testing Chrome is nicer, it pops-up the "unresponsive" alert, whereas Firefox apparently doesn't care.

IIUC, this is a Safari-specific behavior, but it is very inconvenient. I need that dialog to stay up until the user makes a choice. I looked at threading the JFileChooser but that path seems to be way more complicated, and doing all the work in Javascript alone is not possible, for known security reasons. Do you have a clean solution to this?

(*) JVM ends in an InterruptedException

Comment: Can implement it with callbacks and not a "modal dialog"? It can still be a modal-like (e.g. always-on-top) dialog. Need to let the JavaScript return to it's main event pump...

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that, or point me to some more detailed info?

Comment: *"In my test case a Java applet method is called from a javascript function."*  Perhaps the browser is noticing the JS takes too long to complete and that is what is killing it.  If that is the case, the solution might be to have the applet call the script once it is done.  That way the script is not left 'blocking the browser'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the explanation, that's what I figured but I was unsure on the details.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1006499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that dialogs in Java behave as blocking method calls (its actually an amazing engineering trick how they do it that I wish other toolkits would adopt).  So when your javascript invokes the method onto the Java code it's waiting for that dialog to be dismissed.  The browser detects that the javascript thread hasn't returned in a while and simply decides it's dead locked and kills it.  Hence the Java applet goes down with the page.

You'll need to transition that into an asynchronous style interaction.  The call Javascript makes should return immediately.  You can use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() in Java to push that call off the Javascript calling thread.  The trick then is once the dialog is dismissed you need Java to call Javascript.  So you'll have javascript register some sort of callback mechanism.  Something like the following.  I can't remember how external javascript -> java works exactly so this is just pseudo code to illustrate the idea:

```
function showFileDialog() {
    applet.showFileDialog( function( filepath ) {
       if( filepath ) {
          alert( "Hey they picked " + filepath );
       } // must have hit cancel if filepath is null
    } );
}
```

Meanwhile in Java:

```
public void showFileDialog( JavascriptFunction someJavascriptFunction ) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFileChooserDialog chooser = new JFileChooser();
            ...
            int option = chooser.showOpenDialog( parent );

            someJavascriptFunction.invoke( option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ? 
                                           chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath() : 
                                           null );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh man, the pain I've had working on an app entirely implemented with blocking JDialogs...I don't know if I'd wish that on another toolkit ever. ;)

Comment: @chubbard Thanks for the code snippets, they got me in the right direction. The complete solution is slightly more elaborated, since it includes a signed applet but basically looks like above.